How to put the bundle produced by expo export into XCode project created by expo prebuild?
After doing expo prebuild, I get an XCode project that I can compile and (try to) run.
The known problem is, the app crashes with the following error:
No script URL provided. Make sure the packager is running or you have embedded a JS bundle in your application bundle.

unsanitizedScriptURLString = (null)

I've seen recommendations to resolve this issue by starting a Metro server, etc. However, I haven't found a recipe of actually putting the js bundle into the app. I know there's expo export that produces the bundle and puts into dist but dist and ios aren't interconnected in any way.
So the question is, how do I connect them? What is the correct way of putting the files into the app? Copy the files? Enable a build phase in XCode?

The problem is that when running the project in XCode it cannot fetch the js bundle which is why it is important to start the metro server with

npx expo run:ios or npx expo run:android

then you can can compile and run the app in XCode
then XCode can fetch the js bundle from the metro server running on your hardware

So you haven't reached that part of my post?

I've seen recommendations to resolve this issue by starting a Metro server, etc. However, I haven't found a recipe of actually putting the js bundle into the app.

